# WordPress Rest Api search limited to 10 results

Tags: rest-api, json

I went through the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/) and found that to display more than 10 results, I need to add &per_page=30 to the end of the URL

https://www.onyc.hu/wp-json/university/v3/search?term=angol&per_page=30

So I came up with this.

Unfortunately, it is still only displaying 10 search results.
What can I be doing wrong?
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: are you sure that there are actually more than 10 results for this search?

Comment: There certainly should be: https://imgur.com/a/71MJmVY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, there was a wp_query included in the search-route.php file.

Adding 'posts_per_page' => 30, to the query there I guess sent the data through, allowing for the per_page condition to work.

Thanks for looking anyhow!